# google-chart component not updating while data changes dynamically in polymer 2.0?

Tags: polymer, google-visualization, polymer-2.x

I have imported `google-chart` component and tried with sample data. When ever am updating the `data` array, it is not at all reflecting in the UI.
Even i tried with  `this.$.lineChart.redraw();`

Comment: Do you use  array 'set' or 'notifyPath' method as documented here: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/model-data ?

Comment: i updated the array with `this.push("array",{data})` and added notify true in the properties. And am able to push the data to array. But chat is not updating.

Comment: did you set the reflectToAttribute property as true?

Comment: Yes, am able to push data to array. My problem is Chart is not refreshing.

Comment: try to share your codes.

Comment: `<google-chart id="lineChart"
            type='line'
            options='{"title": "Distribution of days"}'
            cols={{optionsForChart}}
            rows="{{dataForLine}}">
          </google-chart>`and

Comment: `forecastLoaded(data){
          this.hide = false;
          this.forecastData = data.detail.response;          
          for(var i=0;i<this.forecastData.list.length;i++){
            this.push("dataForLine",[parseInt(this.forecastData.list[i].main.temp_min),parseInt(this.forecastData.list[i].main.temp_max)]);
          }         
          this.$.lineChart.drawChart();//redraw(this.dataForLine,this.optionsForChart);

        }`

Comment: Try to use a temporary array variable like `tempArray` while push loop. àt your code ` this.push("tempArray",[parseInt(this.forecastData.list[i].‌​main.temp_min),parse‌​Int(this.forecastDat‌​a.list[i].main.temp_‌​max)]); } ` and after loop done. then when finished the loop set it like: `this.set("dataForLine", tempArray);`

Comment: instead of `this.$.lineChart.drawChart();//redraw(this.dataForLine,this.‌​optionsForChart); }`      Remember, loop is async function. so, ensure loop completed then use `this.set("dataForLine", tempArray);` option

Comment: `this.set("dataForLine", tempArray);` is working. Thanks